# How to hide corresponding parent div based on the child div value

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 3 div cols below, they have common class. I want to hide the corresponding div with a specific child ID.

> In this case I want to hide the parent div which has a child div inside with id
>   "ct_sqft_to".

I want to accomplish it with jQuery or CSS (if possible).

```
<div class="col span_3">
</div>
<div class="col span_3">
</div>
<div class="col span_3">
        <label for="ct_sqft_to"> Sq Ft To</label>
        <input type="text" id="ct_sqft_to" class="number" name="ct_sqft_to" size="8" placeholder="Size To - Sq Ft" style="display: inline-block;">
    </div>
```

Comment: Use jquery like this   $("#ct_sqft_to").parent().hide()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just search for the element with the id and get its parent. Something like the following:

`$("#ct_sqft_to").parent().hide();`